# Does Kubernetes not work on Intel?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I've been trying to set up a a local Kubernetes installation on an Ubuntu 16.04 VM by following the setup instructions posted here: http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/kubeadm/

However in section (3/4) when installing a pod network, the following line appears: `If you are on another architecture than amd64, you should use the flannel overlay network as described in the multi-platform section.`

When you scroll down to the multi-platform section the only other architectures it offers are ARM-based: `kubeadm deb packages and binaries are built for amd64, arm and arm64, following the multi-platform proposal.`

Does this mean I can't get Kubernetes to work on an Intel-based machine?

Comment: No, it means Intel licensed AMD64 from AMD and put their own name on it when implementing it on their own chips. *Intel's* 64-bit design is called ia64 and is rarely seen in the wild.

Comment: @hobbs thanks for clarifying, that was puzzling for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

amd64 is one of the ways people describe x86-64 processor instruction sets. Usually for linux distributions people tend to call their images `amd64` because it came along first. Those images work fine on any modern Intel chip.

See also:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/3378/my-processor-is-64-bit-does-that-mean-i-need-the-amd64-image